# For real-valued continuous $f(x)$, $g(x)$, when does $h(f(x))$ = $g(x)$ exist such that h is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be real-valued, continuous, differentiable functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Under what conditions does there exist a continuous and differentiable $h$ such that $h(f(x)) = g(x)$?

For continuity, a sketch of an argument might be;

By continuity we have that for

$|x-x_0| < \delta$,

$|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon_f$ and $|g(x) - g(x_0)| < \epsilon_g$.

Then there exists continuous $h$ since for:

$|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon_f$,

$|h(f(x)) - h(f(x_0))| = |g(x) - g(x_0)| < \epsilon_g$.

What about differentiability?

Comment: I don't really follow the sketch of the argument. But this is a really interesting question in general.

Comment: The argument in words is something like: 

We know that in a small neighborhood of $x$, both $f$ and $g$ also remain in small neighborhoods (not necessarily of the same size) because they are continuous. Then an $h$ which takes $f$ to $g$ will remain in the same small neighborhood $\epsilon_g$ when $x$ remains in $\delta$, so $h$ is continuous.

Comment: For on thing, it needs to be the case that if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $g(x)=g(y)$. This holds even without any continuity.

Comment: If you want differentiability, then you also need that if $f'(x)=0$, then $g'(x)=0$ (why?). If you need continuity then you need that if $f(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence, then so is $g(x_n)$. Not sure if these are sufficient. Also, in my previous comment, I confused $f$ and $g$. Also: should $h$ be defined/continuous/differentiable on all of $\Bbb{R}$ or only on the image of $f$?

Comment: We can assume that the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. I am not sure I understand the previous comment / the confusion about $f$ and $g$.